# Negative characters left on comment edit to be different colour

Tags: feature-request, edits, comments, character-limit

At present it's orange - a low contrast color - and small, hard to see whether you have 27 or -27 characters left, so it's difficult to see that you've gone over the character limit. To be more usable it needs better highlighting.

Comment: Is it small? You can hit CTRL+'+', if you need it bigger. There is a minus in front of the value and the absolute amount goes up when you are in the negative area. So if you are at -27 and keep typing and then you are at -35 and you still ask yourself how many characters are left, well... Isn't that highlighting enough?